# Ionic File Browser return empty array

Tags: ionic-framework, filesystems, ngcordova

I'm quite new to Ionic. I'm facing problem to get the filepath of my file to upload the chosen file. Thus, I created this file browser for my app but it return empty array. I have followed every step shown in [Create A File Browser Using Ionic Framework](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-file-browser-app) but still not working. I included part of my code and the result below. Can someone please explain what's wrong with my code?

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem.root);
    var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    console.log(directoryReader);

    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                console.log(entries);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                // deferred.reject(error);
            });
}
```

[image: Log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to upload my file to the remote server instead of using File Browser. I use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#install) directive to upload files from mobile devices to my remote server. It works perfectly.